# Consequences of MIP*=RE regarding quantum universality

Tags: complexity-theory, church-turing-thesis, mip-star

Provided that $\mathsf{MIP}^*=\mathsf{RE}$ there can be Bell inequalities that have violations achievable only for infinite dimensional quantum systems (vide discussions in [Post1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/528359/implications-of-mip-re-for-physics) and [Post2](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/consequences-of-mip-ast-re-regarding-quantum-algorithms)). Does this implies that this kind of behaviour, once found, will not be simulable by a finite dimensional quantum computer? What are implications for the Church-Turing thesis or its extended quantum version?

Comment: Why limit to the *extended* Church-Turing thesis? Why not ask for implications for the Church-Turing thesis itself?

Comment: You don't need $\mathsf{MIP}^*=\mathsf{RE}$ to see that there are quantum behaviours requiring infinite-dimensional quantum systems (i.e. Hilbert spaces) that cannot be modelled with finite-dimensional systems; this is a consequence of the separation between the $C_q$ and $C_{qs}$ models https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.05116

Comment: I would also recommend reading Scott Aaronson's blog post on the result https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=4512 there are also many good questions and discussions in the comments.

Comment: @Condo thanks for the reference, it is a very interesting one and indeed makes the reference to MIP*=RE unnecessary. Essentially this means that not all physical processes can be captured by finite dimensional Hilbert space dynamics and therefore not all processes can be simulated by quantum computation with qubits? I didn't knew that this was well-known.

Comment: @R.W I think it could depend on your definition of "physical process." Essentially, there are these various models for quantum behaviours, which manifest as these various correlation sets $C_q, C_{qs}$, and $C_{qc}$, but we don't know which one "nature" really abides by. In fact, I've heard it suggested that "physical" correlations should be a closed set, but neither $C_q$ nor $C_{qs}$ has this property.